# R - Using SelectorGadget to grab a dataset

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to grab Hawaii-specific data from this site: https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry. I want to get the data for Hawaii from every table on the site. This is done after selecting the State tab.

In R, I am trying to use rvest library with SelectorGadget.

So far I've tried

```
library(rvest)
html <- read_html("https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry") 
    
html %>% 
html_element("tbody") %>% 
      html_table()
```

However, this isn't giving me what I am looking for yet. I am getting the Global dataset instead in a tibble. So any suggestions on how grab the Hawaii dataset from the State tab?

Also, is there a way to download the dataset that clicks on Download dataset tab? I can also then work from the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the page data is stored in a `script` tag where it is pulled from dynamically in the browser. You can regex out the JavaScript object containing all the data, and write a custom function to extract just the info for Hawaii as shown below. Function `get_state_index` is written to accept a `state` argument, in case you wish to view other states' information.

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

get_state_index <- function(states, state) {
  return(match(T, map(states, ~ {
    .x$name == state
  })))
}

s <- read_html("https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry") %>% html_text()
all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(stringr::str_match(s, "__INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?\\});w\\.")[, 2])
fullbook <- all_data$covidDataCenter$fullbook

hawaii_dataset <- tibble(
  date = fullbook$headers %>% unlist() %>%  as.Date(),
  yoy = fullbook$states[get_state_index(fullbook$states, "Hawaii")][[1]]$yoy %>% unlist()
)
```

---

**Regex:**

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! I didn't know that all page data is stored in a script tag. I'm just learning webscraping in R.

Comment: Btw I was wondering what this part ``"__INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?\\});w\\."`` of the code doing?

Comment: I've added the regex explanation. I am specifying a pattern that allows the regex engine to extract the JavaScript object containing all the data from the response text rvest returns.

Comment: Btw I think they made some changes to their site so this part of the code ``all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(stringr::str_match(s3, "__INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?\\});w\\.")[, 2])`` is giving an error: ``Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       NA
                     (right here) ------^``. Can you please recommend a solution?