# Problems extracting data using JSON in R (getting a lexical error)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Related to the question asked here: [R - Using SelectorGadget to grab a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462414/r-using-selectorgadget-to-grab-a-dataset)

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

get_state_index <- function(states, state) {
  return(match(T, map(states, ~ {
    .x$name == state
  })))
}

s <- read_html("https://www.opentable.com/state-of-industry") %>% html_text()
all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(stringr::str_match(s, "__INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?\\});w\\.")[, 2])
fullbook <- all_data$covidDataCenter$fullbook

hawaii_dataset <- tibble(
  date = fullbook$headers %>% unlist() %>%  as.Date(),
  yoy = fullbook$states[get_state_index(fullbook$states, "Hawaii")][[1]]$yoy %>% unlist()
)
```

I am trying to grab the Hawaii dataset from the State tab. The code was working before but now it is throwing an error with this part of the code:

```
all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(stringr::str_match(s, "__INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?\\});w\\.")[, 2])
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.                                        NA                      (right here) ------^
```

Any proposed solutions? It seems that the website has remained the same for the year but what type of change is causing the code to break?

**EDIT:** The solution proposed by @QHarr:

```
all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(stringr::str_match(s, "__INITIAL_STATE__ = ([\\s\\S]+\\});")[, 2])
```

This was working for a while but then it seems that their website again changed the underlying HTML codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex pattern as shown below to ensure it correctly captures the desired string within the response text i.e. the JavaScript object to use for all_data

```
all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(stringr::str_match(s, "__INITIAL_STATE__ = ([\\s\\S]+\\});")[, 2])
```

[image]

Note: in R the single escape is doubled e.g. `\\s` rather than shown `\s` above.

Comment: How do I know what regex pattern to change though? They seem to be changing it every now and then. Right now the regex pattern you have posted in the solutions isn't working anymore.

Comment: Is it from looking at this: 

window.__INITIAL_STATE__={"authModal":{"isAuthModalOpen":f...}
 })(window)
                </script><script>_otbootstrap();</script><script>
                            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                                var preloadPaths = JSON.parse("[]")
                               ..........;
                                })
                            });

Comment: I'll have a look on weekend. Please remind me.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the problem yet? Thanks