# Unable to get correct CSS tag for webscraping in R using SelectorGadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to web scrape data in `R` from this url but cannot seem to get the correct `css` tag. For now I just need help retrieving the professor's name. Any help would be appreciated. I am using the **Selector Gadget** to get the `css` tag.

https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search/teachers?query=*&sid=1245

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search/teachers?query=*&sid=1245"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(css=".cJdVEK") %>%
  html_text()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVwBP.png

Comment: The required info is located in a script tag here `'https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search/teachers?query=*&sid=1245' %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('script') %>% .[8] %>% html_text()` you need regex to extract required info. Similar question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71614254/problems-extracting-data-using-json-in-r-getting-a-lexical-error

Comment: A regex answer here https://regex101.com/r/hcE14X/2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the names with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search/teachers?query=*&sid=1245')

web_Obj_Popup <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div[5]/div/div/button")
web_Obj_Popup$clickElement()

for(i in 1 : 100)
{
  print(i)
  remDr$executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 25)")
}

web_Obj_Teacher_Name <- remDr$findElements("class name", "cJdVEK")
professor_Names <- lapply(X = web_Obj_Teacher_Name, FUN = function(x) x$getElementText()[[1]])
professor_Names
```